# Issue withDocker Selenium Grid on VM

Tags: docker, selenium-grid

I'm running docker grid for selenium on VM.
Using a compose a file to set up selenium grid

Getting a below error message:

```
Cleaning up stale test sessions on the unregistered node http://172.17.0.4:5555
Registered a node http://172.17.0.4:5555
Marking the node http://172.17.0.4:5555 as down: cannot reach the node for 2 tries
```

Details:
**VM :   Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)**

docker-compose file:

```
hub:
  image: selenium/hub
  ports:
    - "4444:4444"
firefoxnode:
  image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
  links:
    - hub
  expose:
   - "5555"
```

please help me to resolve this